# Privilege page contradicts the FAQ; which is correct?

Tags: support, asking-questions, privileges

The ["Remove new user restrictions" privilege page says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) that a new user cannot:

> ask or answer questions too rapidly

suggesting that this rate limit is removed at 10 rep. But [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/339911) has a different point of view:

> Users < 125 rep, 40 minutes, network-wide

Which is correct?

[Original question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4739/176217) posted on ruSO.meta and not yet answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: @gnat the whole point of this question is that this *isn't* explained in that post (it makes no mention of removed limits for asking/answering at 10 rep)

Comment: @Cai getting over 10 rep (but still under 125) does not remove rate limit to ask - neither network wide nor at the site where rep is earned, that's why it's not mentioned in the guide. 10-rep privileges page could probably be updated to clarify that rate limit stays there until 125 rep

Comment: So the answer to this question is "the privilege page is wrong"; closing a question asking why the rate limit page contradicts another page as a dupe of the rate limit page makes absolutely no sense at all @gnat

Comment: @Cai this question is "How much rep is needed to ask more than one question in 40 mins" and the answer is in the duplicate (guide). Correctness of privileges page would be a different question

Comment: @gnat that's the title... not the body of the question. The question is "x page says something, y page says something else; which is correct?"

Comment: body of the question is "Which is correct?" and the answer to the body is, again, in the duplicate: rate limiting guide is correct

Comment: @gnat the answer isn't in the rate limiting guide at all; if the rate limit guide said what it currently does *and* said "the new-user privilege page is wrong" then it would be a duplicate. Closing this helps no one, doesn't make it obvious that the privilege page is wrong and guarantees the privilege page won't be fixed if it is indeed wrong.

Comment: @gnat as it stands now, the rate limit guide does not have answer for this and isn't proper dupe target. If you can edit it to be correct and explain what is asked here then it would be proper dupe, personally I'm not sure what exactly is going on, if it's a bug or not, so can't really edit. But as Cai said, it's wrong to close something as dupe of faq post when the faq doesn't have the answer yet. (or else we can close all questions as dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and be done with)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand that it is possible to interpret this question as you suggest. However per my reading its title and text are currently too ambiguous to reliably do so

Comment: @gnat well guess we can't convince each other then. In case it will be closed, I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like, at 10 reputation, you can ask/answer more rapidly *on that site*. The network-wide rate-limiting only ends at 125. See [this meta.SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore/322265#322265).

Comment: Do you have any more information about this?